# I am not getting the correct result in the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created the demo below to make it easier to understand and help. I hope it was clear for you to help me. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/9

As can be understood from the SQL query, I want to print mp3 files to the screen. But if you run the query, you can see the result from you that the output of the query is wrong.

post_file id and upload_id are actually the same ids. Please look at the post_id and upload_ids to figure out what's wrong.

So `post_file 2,9` in `post_id 1` is actually `upload_id 2` and `upload_id 9` in the `i_user_uploads` table.

According to this condition, how can I print only `upload_file_ext = 'mp3'` data to the screen using `post_id`, `post_file` and `upload_id`.

The query I wrote is as follows. You can check the **[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/9)** below to run the query with the tables.

```
SELECT P.*,
       U.*,
       A.*
FROM i_friends F FORCE INDEX(ixFriend)
INNER JOIN i_posts P FORCE INDEX (ixForcePostOwner) ON P.post_owner_id = F.fr_two 
INNER JOIN i_users U FORCE INDEX (ixForceUser) ON P.post_owner_id = U.iuid  AND U.uStatus IN('1','3')  AND F.fr_status IN('me', 'flwr', 'subscriber')  
INNER JOIN i_user_uploads A FORCE INDEX (iuPostOwner) ON P.post_owner_id = A.iuid_fk 
AND P.post_file <> ''  AND A.uploaded_file_ext = 'mp3'
WHERE P.post_owner_id='1'
ORDER BY P.post_id
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: @P.Salmon The result should consist of posts with mp3 extension in the `i_user_uploads` table. But this has to be done using the `post_id` and `post_file` in the `i_posts` table.

Comment: I ask because output looks fine to me.

Comment: @P.Salmon Please look at the uploaded_file_path results there is same result with same upload_id

Comment: @P.Salmon https://ibb.co/vhgnTq7 this is what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a add an equality test -

```
SELECT P.*,U.*,A.*
     FROM i_friends F FORCE INDEX(ixFriend)
      INNER JOIN i_posts P FORCE INDEX (ixForcePostOwner)
      ON P.post_owner_id = F.fr_two 
      INNER JOIN i_users U FORCE INDEX (ixForceUser)
      ON P.post_owner_id = U.iuid AND U.uStatus IN('1','3') AND F.fr_status IN('me', 'flwr', 'subscriber')  
      INNER JOIN i_user_uploads A FORCE INDEX (iuPostOwner)
      ON P.post_owner_id = A.iuid_fk 
      AND P.post_file <> '' 
      AND A.uploaded_file_ext = 'mp3'
and cast(p.post_file as int) = upload_id
        WHERE P.post_owner_id='1'
        ORDER BY P.post_id;
```

BTW does force index really improve performance here?

Comment: Are you sure you got the output? Because I am getting error.

Comment: Hi P.Salmon, I got what you missed. You added cast but you didn't signed anything. I have changed added signed in your change like `cast(P.post_file as signed int) = A.upload_id` and then it worked.

Comment: The `cast` solution is working fine but not enough. Because if there is multiple id in the `P.post_file` like `1,2` or `2,3` then the cast checking just first ids'. Is there any way to check all `id`s after the commas ? Please check this [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/11) . I this demo you can see post_file ids. Please check the screenshots I have created for you to understand what is wrong in the query after cast https://ibb.co/YPzhZsW
https://ibb.co/bg2ph8z

Comment: This might be that you need FIND_IN_SET() instead of the cast() operation. replace `AND cast(p.post_file as int) = upload_id` with `AND FIND_IN_SET(A.upload_id, P.post_file)`